# my splash screen video keep playing in the background

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, android-videoview

My splash screen format is mp4, it works well when I run the app, but if I exit the application and back to it, I see a black screen and the video keeps playing in the background

**how can I make the video pause and resume automatically ?**

- this is my MainActivity.java

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    VideoView videoView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags((WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON));

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video);

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {



            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                if (isFinishing())
                    return;

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
                finish();
            }



        });
    }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

pause video playback on activity's `onPause` lifecycle event, stop and release video player on `onStop`, and also start video playback `onStart` and resume on `onResume`.For pause and resume you should store current position and resume accordingly.

Comment: I fixed the problem but the video start from the beginning, I tried release(); but I got this message "cannot resolve method release" what should I do now

Comment: @SerenaSwift you can find all these things in [MediaPlayer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)